# Microsoft Test Manager cannot install test agent on these machines

Tags: testing, automated-tests, mtm

I am trying to create a new environment using microsoft test manager. Unfortuntely I get the following error:

Microsoft Test Manager cannot install test agent on these machines. Possible causes:
- Machines are not running or they are not available on the network
- The File and Printer Sharing exception is not enabled on the machines.

Controller is up and running , the user and password is correct. Firewall is disabled. File and Printer sharing exception too.

I do not know what is going on. How could it be solved? Do not know how to go further with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try running MTM as  Administrator. Also check the article on MSDN
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a790f8d3-489d-4fd6-9204-2fb1f7e21b50/microsoft-test-manager-cannot-install-test-agent-on-these-machines?forum=vsmantest&tduid=(bbfad4796548274f6ccbc9c1b7d15461)(256380)(2459594)(XdSn0e3h3.k-lkj0MqSQojhOnvvQ2ym5yA)()